# convergence of $a_n = e^{nzi \pi /4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

If we have series $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $a_n=e^{nzi \frac{\pi}{4}}$. Where does this series convergence/divergences?

If I do the ratio test I get

\begin{align}
r&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \Bigg| \frac{e^{nzi \pi/4}e^{zi\pi/4}}{e^{nzi \pi/4}} \Bigg| \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\Big|e^{zi\pi/4}\Big| \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big|e^{i\pi/4}\Big||e^z| \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}|e^z|=|e^x e^{iy}|=e^x
\end{align}
Makes sense?

Comment: How is $e^x>1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I don't understand how you got to the third line from the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, performing the ratio test gives $$r = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left| {\frac{{{a_{n + 1}}}}{{{a_n}}}} \right| = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left| {{e^{zi\frac{\pi }{4}}}} \right|$$if we replace $z = x + iy$, we get $$r = \left| {{e^{i\frac{\pi }{4}x}}} \right|\left| {{e^{ - \frac{\pi }{4}y}}} \right| = {e^{ - \frac{\pi }{4}y}}$$so according to the obtained result, the series converges for the upper half of the complex plane ($y>0$) and diverges for the lower half. For the real axis ($y=0$) no conclusion could be drawn from this test. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: What do you mean with no conclusions could be drawn from this test?

Comment: @ELEC If the ratio test gives $1$ then the test is inconclusive about the convergence or divergence of the series and another method should be used.

Comment: Ahhh. Yeah I get that. But we know for sure that it converges then $y>0$. I guess that's good enough for me :) Thank you.